# C# WPF Prism PopupWindowAction События окна

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

Хочу сделать свою "non client area"  в popup окне. Как и где мне можно работать с code-behind PopupWindowAction окна? Можно ли реагировать на события  PopupWindowAction окна в ViewModel UserControl? Application.Current.Windows отдает окна но как управлять именно етим окном?

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CustomPopupRequest}">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" >
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
                    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <WindowChrome UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" CaptionHeight="0"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
            <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
                <views:AddObjectUserControl />
            </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction>
    </prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Получил окно в code-behind UserControl с помощью Window.GetWindow(this). Буду рад лучшим решениям

Comment: Вариантов два. Вы делаете у контрола свойство к которому биндите свойство ViewModel. При получении события, то что нужно передать во ViewModel присваиваете в свойство UserControl-а. Во ViewModel подписываеетсь на изменение свойства. Второй вариант, вы делаете не свойство, а команду и при получении события вызываете ее метод Exceute с передачей необходимых параметров.